# iTerm2 keyboard shortcut - split pane navigation

Tags: terminal, iterm, terminal-emulator

I have been a long time user of the standard Mac Terminal. Decided to experiment with iTerm2 after hearing good things about it from my colleagues.

One of the more useful features I am seeing on iTerm2 is its split panes (much like vim split buffers).

In vim, I can move between split buffers using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+`arrowkeys`. Is there a keyboard shortcut for iTerm2 to move between panes as well?

Comment: mac shortcut of usefulness: `⌘`+`⇧`+`/` and then try a few keywords (in this case split) in the search bar. Use the `↓` to view the menu items, if there is a built-in shortcut you will see it alongside the menu item. works on most mac applications, ie Excel, sublime, firefox, etc.

Comment: I have mixed feeling about this question ... although I think it' useful, shouldn't key bindings have a proper place to the Q/A?

Answer (score 686, accepted):

[From the documentation:](http://www.iterm2.com/documentation-one-page.html)

> <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>  navigates among split panes in order of use.

Comment: I'm using those commands to strobe my screen to the dubstep track playing in the office.

Comment: This does not work with a German keyboard… better use ⌘+⌥+← or ⌘+⌥+→, see my answer below.

Comment: @Bombe you could also try `⌘+⌥+[` or `⌘+⌥+]`. That worked for me on a spanish keyboard

Comment: @RickyCheers nope, doesn’t work on German keyboards; `[` and `]` both require additional keys to be pressed.

Comment: Damn you apple, with the complete ass-backwards German key layout!

Comment: This used to work on my machine but after last OS X upgrade it stopped working as well as some other shell shortcuts (not part of iTerm). However, @Bombe 's answer with arrow keys still works and is even easier to use.

Comment: `[` and `]` are also impossible to use on the french layout, `⌘+⌥+arrow-keys` wins

Answer (score 175):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> navigate similarly to vim's C-w hjkl.

Comment: Is it possible to change this hoteky to use opt only?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r you can add custom short cut keys in your iterm2 profile (Preferences -> Profiles/<Your Profile>/Keys). There you have actions "Select Split Pane Above", "Select Split Pane Below", "Above" "Down".

Answer (score 116):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> will let you navigate split panes in the direction of the arrow, i.e. when using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to split panes vertically, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> will let you switch between the panes.

Comment: This answer works best and is most intuitive!.
Thanks

Comment: I have changed my config a lot, but I had to set these keys up before they worked.

Comment: @mrfred now if only iTerm was configurable… OH WAIT IT IS.

Comment: For reference, if you want to remap this to e.g. Cmd-Up Arrow, Cmd-Down Arrow, Cmd-Left Arrow and Cmd-Right Arrow to nagivate accordingly between split panes, you can do this by remapping these respective keys to  "Select Split Pane Above" and its Below, Left, Right companions in Preferences -> Profiles/<Your Profile>/Keys

Comment: I second mrfred

Comment: This should be the best answer. This one actually helps

Comment: In case anyone is interested `⌘`+`Shift`+`D` splits panes horizontally.

Answer (score 7):

there is configuration in the following way:

`Preferences -> keys -> Navigation shortcuts`

the 3rd option: shortcut to choose a split pane is "no shortcut" by default, we can choose one

cheers

Comment: This, in my opinion, should be the no. 1 answer because it allows you a few options on hotkeys. 
Those options are:  
- `No Shortcut`, 
- `⌥ + Number`, 
- `⌘ + Number`, 
- and `⌥ + ⌘ + Number`. 

It should be noted that choosing `⌘ + Number` will conflict with the default key combination for switching between tabs.

Comment: This answer works best and is most intuitive! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was using Terminator before, so I found it convenient to re-map Alt + arrow-key to switch between the panes. This can be done in Preferences -> Keys -> Key Mappings - press the '+' button to add a mapping. Also, in my case such a mapping was already defined in Profiles, I simply removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Spanish ISO:

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> goes left top
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> goes bottom right